# Mongoose: efficiently upsert multiple records and their sub records

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building a Node/MongoDB/Mongoose synchronisation server app.

A stripped down version of my schema looks like this:

```
let dayTimeline = new mongoose.Schema({
  deviceId: { type: String, trim: true, required: true, index: true }, /* device identifier */
  day:      { type: Number, required: true, index: true },
  started:  { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 }, /* started in seconds from 1970 */
  ended:    { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 }, /* ended in seconds from 1970 */
  duration: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 }, /* duration in seconds from 1970 */
  timeline: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'TimelineItem' }]
}
```

Where the timeline property is intended to be an array of references to instances of:

```
let timelineItem = new mongoose.Schema({
    deviceId: { type: String, trim: true, required: true, index: true }, /* device identifier */
    started:  { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 }, /* started in seconds from 1970 */
    ended:    { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 }, /* ended in seconds from 1970 */
    duration: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 } /* duration in seconds from 1970 */
                });
```

The client application passes an array of 20 dayTimeline json dictionaries to the server son app and each of those contains an array of 10-20 timelineItem json dictionaries.

I want the data passed from the client to overwrite/update the server data.

**What is the most efficient way to insert/update the data using mongoose?**

In the client app I'm using Realm where I can specify a primary id key for both objects that is a combination of the deviceId and started values which makes a unique identifier - I thought that I might be able to do something similar on the server but my knowledge of mongoose is quite limited.

Comment: The most "efficient" way would be to actually "embed" the "timeline" data instead of referencing it, because it's far more "efficient" to write to one collection rather than "two". So aside from that as a general fact, it kind of divulges into opinion based without a more specific explanation of how the data is supposed to be used. But on the surface, it looks like you just jumped to the conclusion of another collection because that's how you would do it in a different database.

Comment: So would you please care to elaborate why this would not be so? Or otherwise further outline your data usage pattern so there is at least scope for a definitive answer?

Comment: Thanks for the help @NeilLunn - yes there's a good reason to have a separate timelineItem class/object. The timelineItem objects also have an optional reference to a 'place' object. I want to be able to make queries to retrieve all timelineItem objects that reference the same place instance for example.

Comment: Is this an unusual requirement?